# How to run insecure content using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm using chrome extension to add  in https://* pages, but when I want to load pages from http://*, chrome blocked the page saying:

> [blocked] The page at https://* ran insecure content from http://*.

So I wonder, is there any method or API to avoid such situation?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You cant unless you change the chrome security policy which can't be done from code, each user would need to do it and will be a security risk for those users.